# Who is the biggest god in hinduism?

Tags: gods

Who is the biggest god in hinduism? I mean the god who is not created by other god or the god who exist before all of other gods? The purpose to ask this question is to identify the the biggest character in Hinduism. As other religious peoples consider the God is the one not created by others and he is the one existing before each and every creation. So the answer may help to identify who is the god in hinduism equal to the god in other religion.

Comment: The God who is not created by another God and who existed before all other Gods is Brahman. Brahman is That which existed before and always will. Vaishnavas say that Brahman is Vishnu, Shaivites say that Brahman is Shiva, while Advaita says that Brahman is The Reality and Brahma, Vishnu and Shiva are One, but different forms of this Formless, Nirguna called as Brahman. All the best. I don't think this is a duplicate but I think it could be opinion-based as different sects would claim that their God is the biggest. It will result in clashes between different sects, thereby dividing the user

Comment: I'm also Hindu. The reason to ask question is to answer other religious peoples. On their point of view god is one. So they surprised on our concept. What they see as god is the one who is not created by others and the person who is their before every thing. So in hinduism we need to be able to answer who is the biggest not by strength. just by the first of every one. Is there any answer to it?

Comment: Yes in that sense the closest Hindu concept of the ever-present God is Brahman. Brahman is eternal and ever-present. Here is more information about Brahman (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahman). Different sects believe different things about Brahman, for example, Vaishnavas believe that Brahman is none other than Lord Vishnu. Shaivites believe that Lord Shiva is Brahman. Advaitas believe that Brahman is the reality and Shiva and Vishnu are different forms of the same Brahman. All the best. Please note that the word 'Brahman (with an 'n') and the word 'Brahma (without 'n')  are differ. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But it is new to me Brahma and Brahman. What is that?

Comment: Brahma (without 'n') is one among the Trimurthi. Here is a picture of Trimurthi (http://worldreligionswiki7.wikispaces.com/file/view/trimurti.jpg/130377089/trimurti.jpg) The one with four heads is Brahma (without 'n'), the one in center is MahaVishnu and the one on the right is Lord Parameshvara. So that is Brahma (without 'n'). Apart from this there is another concept called as Brahman (with n). This Brahman is omni-present and is God. Here is some more info about Brahman please read it it will answer your doubts. All the best.http://www.hinduwebsite.com/brahmanmain.asp

Comment: Thank you very much. This is the first time I got the different between Brahman and Brahma. And I thing I got correct answer to the other religious people regarding the God of hinduism. You can put it as an answer to make it as green. And I change the question also to reflect expected meaning.